# Move Image to another Path from a clicked link; Codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, hyperlink, move

The idea is to move an image selected by the current user to another path that's also in the database. Here is the Controller:

```
public function makeProfile()  {             
         if (isset($_GET['makeProfile']));           
         $data['user_id']= $this->session->userdata['user_id'];                      
                 $fileName = ('uploads/'.$fileName);              
    if($this->images_model->makeProfile($data, $fileName)) {            
         echo "Success";             
                     $msg = 'File successfully moved to profile';
        redirect(site_url().'main/');             
         }else{         
         echo "Failure";
```

The Model:

```
Public function makeProfile ($data, $fileName) {
return $this->db->get_where('images', ['user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')])->row();
move_uploaded_file('uploads/'.$fileName, 'uploads/profile/'.$fileName);
if($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') {
return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
   }
```

The VIEW:

```
<a class="profile" href="<?= base_url('main/makeProfile') ?>">Make Profile</a>
```

I’m probably going about this all wrong, but hoping someone here might steer me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any and all input!

Comment: why you are getting record from images table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `makeProfile` in the model has an issue. You are getting the record and then returning it back. The code below is not executing

```
Public function makeProfile ($data, $fileName) {
   $fileName= $this->db->get_where('images', ['user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')])->row()->image;

    // Will copy foo/test.php to bar/test.php
   // overwritting it if necessary
   copy('uploads/'.$fileName, 'uploads/profile/'.$fileName));
   if($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') {
      return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

Quoting a couple of relevant sentences from its manual page :

> Makes a copy of the file source to dest.
>
> If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: Are you suggesting only copying instead of move_uploaded_file? Would you say the model and view are OK?

Comment: Ok, I see you also removed the "return" statememt. Will try and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: After making those changes, I'm still getting the error "undefined variable: $fileName" Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong there?

Comment: @dreamerdan I've made changes in model function.

Comment: The reason to remove `return` is that return was sending back DB query response and code below it was not executing. Due to this `move_uploaded_file()` not working

Comment: I changed the last item "image" to "image_id" 'cause that the column that's in the database. I was getting an error of undefined property with "image". Only now I'm getting the following error on the copy statement:

copy(uploads211): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. 

That seems strange since I upload images OK to this directory. I'm also using  WAMPSERVER 3.1.0. Not sure if that has something to do with it. 

But thanks so much for following up with me on this!

Comment: @dreamerdan in `copy()` 1st parameter is the path of the directory where the image is existing with image name and extension and the 2nd parameter new path and image name

Comment: I posted another related question about deleting the image. Once I find the right variable to the image name or path, I can use the same with this question here. Right now file is copying over to the other path, but it's copying only the first file in the db list. Similar problem I'm having with deleting. It's deleting ALL images which tells me I have to find a way to assign a variable to the user's selection. If you see the new question you should see get information. Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue and responded to might question on it. Hopefully someone else might be able to benefit from it. Thanks!